# File not found: mtbs/builds/z.iOS/yyy/Resources/Images.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage/Contents.json

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get an error when I try to build a xamarin forms project for ios. it says:
File not found: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/yyy.iOS/75685cd3b44330ec65532060f5af8281/Resources/Images.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage/Contents.json
even though the Contents.json file exists in the specified location.

Comment: Refer this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/125116/file-not-found-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I add a new file to Resources, but forget to include it to my VS project. Then the same error appears.

Check if the file is included in your project in the Solution Explorer. If not, click on the folder and then there is [a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg9Vy.jpg) in the Solution Explorer called **“Show All Files”**.

Then find your file, right click on it and press **“Include in Project”**.